# NSError __autoreleasing vs _Nullable

Tags: objective-c, error-handling, automatic-ref-counting

I have always known this pattern was the way to manage an `NSError**` parameter (specifically the `BOOL` return value and `NSError* __autoreleasing *` parameter:

```
-(BOOL)doSomethingWithString:(NSString*)string error:(NSError* __autoreleasing *)error {
    if(![string length]) {
        *error = [NSError blah blah];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
 }
```

To use this method followed this pattern:

```
NSError* error = nil;
if([self doSomethingWithString:@"" error:&error]) {
    //great success!!
} else {
    //log error
}
```

Now it seems that `__autoreleasing` is replaced with `_Nullable`?

I'm looking at this method from the official Apple Documentation:  https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsfilemanager/1415371-createdirectoryaturl?language=objc

So, do I simply replace all of my `__autoreleasing` with `_Nullable` and all is good in this situation?  If not, what is the new pattern for managing `NSError**` parameters?

Comment: The pattern is that on success you return YES or a non-nil object, and on failure you return NO or nil.

Comment: @gnasher729 I fixed my example...thanks for pointing that out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, these are 2 different things.

`__autoreleasing` specifies variable mode for ARC, so it can properly deduct how to read and write to it.

Nullability specifies... well whether parameter can be `nil` or not.

I think the confusion is caused by fact that Clang automatically assumes `__autoreleasing` for indirect parameters (http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#indirect-parameters), so some people just omit it. And if I remember correctly it wasn't always the case.

Otherwise you would end up with `* __autoreleasing _Nullable *`.
But it's not a bad thing to be explicit!